# Can I use spark 2.3.0 and pyspark to do stream processing from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am going to do stream processing with pyspark and use Kafka as a data source.

I see that Kafka 0.10 connector is not supported under Spark Python API.

Can I use Kafka 0.8 connector in Spark 2.3.0 regardless it is deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

It's deprecated, but not deleted. You can use it.

However, you may be interested in Structured Streaming, which has Kafka 0.10 support in Python - link [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). This is the new Streaming API in Spark, that will replace DStreams

Comment: I believe the OP didn't like your answer thus the downvote.